# How to join tables and return multiple values in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, order_product and color. order_product has got product_code and color_code and color has got color_code and color_name, user sends a product_code I need to get the all related color_code for the given product_code and return the color_name from the color table using color_code.

ex:

```
order_product:

product_code    color_code

    code1           GRN
    code1           RED


color:

color_code    color_name

GRN           Green
RED           Red
```

If the user sends code1, I need to return Green and Red. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a simple [join](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins) can do it:

```
 $values=DB::table('order_product')->
     join('color','color.color_code','=','order_product.color_code')
         ->where('order_product.product_code',$productCodeInput)->select('color.color_name')->get();
```